# Set Flash in Symfony 2.1

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have been adapting our code in preparation of moving our code to the new 2.1 Symfony codebase.

In 2.0.* we could set Flash messages by simply calling the session service in our controller using the following

```
$this->get('session')->setFlash('type', 'message');
```

I have trawled through the new documentation, I was just wondering if there was a clean way, similar to the above; rather than just calling the FlashBagInterface?

Comment: Ahh, bingo!

    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('type', 'message');

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('type', 'message');
```

Answer (score 13):

Also, you might want to try the `add()` method instead, which won't obliterate other flash messages:

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('type', 'message');
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI:

The Symfony HttpFoundation component has a very powerful and flexible session subsystem which is designed to provide session management through a simple object-oriented interface using a variety of session storage drivers.

**FlashBagInterface has a simple API:**

- set(): Sets an attribute by key;
- get(): Gets an attribute by key;
- all(): Gets all attributes as an array of key => value;
- has(): Returns true if the attribute exists;
- replace(): Sets multiple attributes at once: takes a keyed array and sets each key => value pair;
- remove(): Deletes an attribute by key;
- clear(): Clear all attributes.

Source: [Symfony2: Session Management](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html:)